# Can I use "camping up" here?

Tags: expressions

The police **are camping (up)** on the parking lot outside the mall where the hostage situation is taking place.

Can I use "camping up" here to mean that they are setting up their trailers and more? Or what else could I write?

Answer (score 3):

You can say, "The police **are setting up camp** on the parking lot..." to indicate that they are currently setting up their trailers and other equipment.  If you say, "They **are camping** in the parking lot..." then that means that they have already finished setting up and are just occupying the parking lot.

The phrasal verb [**to camp [something] up**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/camp-up) has a completely different meaning and refers to [**camp** as an aesthetic style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camp_(style)) that is closely associated with gay culture.  So if you say, "The police are **camping up** their trailers..." then the image it suggests is that they are decorating their trailers with glitter and sequins or something like that. You should avoid **camp up** as a phrase unless you're definitely talking about *RuPaul's Drag Race* or something like that.

Comment: You can go camping up on a mountain without it implying any particular aesthetic style. But more often we "camp out" rather than "camp up".

Comment: Bearing in mind the advice in the answer, you could use **up** or **down** after camping in this context if the parking lot was clearly situated above or below your location.